# Lower pressure lower boiling point

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, phase-transition, phase-diagram

Is there an intuitive way for understanding why in lower pressure the boiling point is lower? Maybe some easy characteristic special case.
Or should I just follow equation or experiment and memorize this fact.

I am beginner in physics so advices like for kid are allowed.

Comment: Consider reviewing the Wikipedia article on [boiling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling); you’ll find your answer in the first paragraph. Boiling occurs when the vapor pressure (which increases exponentially with increasing temperature) exceeds the surrounding pressure. A lower ambient pressure therefore results in a lower boiling temperature.

Comment: The intuitiv way: look in water which is heated, you will see on the bottom little bubbles , the grow  since the pressure of vapor inside rises and in the moment this pressure rises tu the outside pressure the become very big and go up.

Answer (score 2):

Boiling occurs when bubbles are able to form below the surface of the liquid.  In order for a bubble to form, it must push back the surrounding liquid.  For this to happen, its pressure must be as high as that of the surrounding liquid.  For typically small depths, the pressure of the surrounding liquid is about equal to that of the atmosphere above.  So the lower the atmospheric pressure, the lower the equilibrium vapor pressure inside the liquid has to be for boiling to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Boiling occurs when the *vapor pressure* of the hot liquid equals the *atmospheric pressure* of its surroundings. When you reduce the pressure of its surroundings, it takes less vapor pressure to equal that, which occurs at a *lower temperature*.

This is why reducing the ambient pressure reduces the boiling point temperature of a liquid.